# Collatz sequence including the user value in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I include the user input value in the very first place in the output?

here is my code below:

```
seq = []
n = int(input("\nEnter a number (greater than 1): "))
while (n > 1):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    seq.append(n)
print()
print(*seq)
```

So when I entered 6, it was printed like this:

```
3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

My entered value (which MUST be included) is missing.
Please help!

Comment: Think about how you can add things to `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you add `n` to `seq` at the end of every iteration. To add the initial value of `n`, simply do `seq.append(n)` before entering the while loop:

```py
seq = []
n = int(input("\nEnter a number (greater than 1): "))
seq.append(n)   # this is the addition you need
while (n > 1):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    seq.append(n)
print()
print(*seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.  I believe the most logical way is to move your seq.append(n) statement to the first line of your while loop to capture your input.  The issue will then be that 1 will be dropped off the end of the list.  To fix that, you change your while loop condition to capture the one and add a condition to break out of the while loop:

```
seq = []
n = int(input("\nEnter a number (greater than 1): "))
while (n > 0):
    seq.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        break
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = 3 * n + 1

print()
print(*seq)

#output:
Enter a number (greater than 1): 6

6 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```